# Best practice for returning "error" from a function

Tags: php, function

I have a function:

```
public function CustomerRating() {
     $result = $db->query("...");
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

     if($row)
          $output = $row['somefield'];
     } else {
          $output = "error";
     }

     return $output;
}

//somewhere on another page...
if(is_numeric($class->CustomerRating()) {
     echo $class->CustomerRating;
} else {
      echo "There is an error with this rating.";
}
```

Is there a better way to find errors? In this function, if no rows are returned, it doesn't mean an "error" per se, it simply means the value can't be calculated. When I check for the result of a function, I feel like there is a better way to check the data being returned before I display it in the if function. What's the best way to do this? I'd like to return a "false", but how would I check for that when calling the function? Thanks!

Comment: well, its not really an error (if it where an error you would use  `throw new Exception('There is an error with this rating.');`just return `null` or `false` and let the application handle it accordingly

Comment: @Hannes - I agree.  There isn't an error here.  The Exception bit is useful, but not here.  If pressed, I would say that a `null` return value is the most appropriate.

Comment: @thetaiko I agree with you agreeing with me :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are (in my opinion) 2 common ways:

1. **Returning** `false`
   Many builtin PHP functions do that
2. **Using [SPL exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php)**
   Evolved PHP frameworks (Symfony2, ZF2, ...) do that

Comment: I took your advice and now just return `false`. This seems to work the best. Thanks!

Comment: @Florent How I do to return  `false` and the explanation of the error?

Comment: Only problem with just returning false, is that if there are several different "errors", you give no information about which one was encountered.

Answer (score 5):

You need [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
public function CustomerRating() {
     $result = $db->query("...");
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
     if ($row !== null) {
          return $row['somefield'];
     } else {
          throw new Exception('There is an error with this rating.');
     }
}

// Somewhere on another page...
try {
    echo $class->CustomerRating();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Almost perfect, the proper way to do this would be `if (!$row) throw...` otherwise `return` at the end of the function. And you're missing an opening `{`.

Answer (score 3):

Use exceptions.  Avoid returning errors from functions and methods

Answer (score 3):

Although returning false to indicate an error is prevalent in PHP libraries, there are several drawbacks:

1. you can not return a description about the error
2. if the false value is a valid return value of the function, then you can not use this approach

Another approach I see in my job is to return an array with both the normal result and the possible error, basically returning a pair, but then to get the real result you have to retrieve it from the array which is more unpleasant code to write

Exceptions are a full fledged solution to this problem but it's a bit cumbersome to write the try...catch block for simple errors. For a function that's documented to throw an exception, if you don't catch the exception when you call it, PhpStorm will complain about that, so in my opinion exceptions are better reserved for more severe errors

One way to return both the result and a possible error is to use a pass by reference parameter, which is used a lot in Objective C

```
/**
 * get element from array
  * @param $index int
  * @param $list array
  * @param $error object
  */
function getFromArray($index, $list, &$error=null) {
    if ($index >= 0 && $index < count($list)) {
        return $list[$index];
    }

    $error = "out of index";
    return null;
}

$list = ['hello', 'world'];

$error = null;
$result = getFromArray(-1, $list, $error);
if ($error) {
    echo "an error occurred " . $error;
} else {
    echo $result;
}
```

if you don't care about the error, you can just call the function leaving out the error parameter

```
echo getFromArray(0, $list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) - Saves on the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to deal with errors is to throw an exception. that way you can have all kinds of different errors and handle them accordingly.

you can then just do:

```
try {
    $myvar = CustomerRating();
    //do something with it
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
public function CustomerRating() {
     $result = $db->query("...");
     $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

     if($row){
         $output = $row['somefield'];
     } else {
         $output = false;
     }

     return $output;
}

//somewhere on another page...
if($class->CustomerRating() !== false) {
     echo $class->CustomerRating();
} else {
     echo "There is an error with this rating.";
}
```

This will make sure that it won't break if you return a zero.